# Null handling in Java 1.7 and 1.6

Tags: java, struts

I have a below dropdown which will be populated and visible upon some action in same JSP

```
    <s:select id="xyzName" label="Source" key="sourceName"
     headerKey="1" headerValue="Select Source" list="#session.SOURCE_LIST"     cssStyle="width:334px" value="source" onchange="document.sourceForm.submit();">
</s:select>
```

I ran this code in Tomcat 7, I used Java 1.7 for compiling the code and it worked fine.

I ran the same code in Tomcat 6, I used Java 1.6 for compiling the code. If same action is performed then dropdown is not visible at all and there is no Exception in the backend.

I researched and found that initially while loading the page it is checking for the values of dropdown in session, and as it is null it is not displaying anything.

I modified the code as below and it worked fine

```
<s:if test="(#session.SOURCE_LIST != null && !#session.SOURCE_LIST.isEmpty()) ">
<s:select id="xyzName" label="Source" key="sourceName"
headerKey="1" headerValue="Select Source" list="#session.SOURCE_LIST" cssStyle="width:334px" value="source" onchange="document.sourceForm.submit();">
</s:select>
</s:if>
```

I am curious whether null is handled by default in Java 1.7 and not in 1.6. Any suggestions on this.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not about Java versions: but about the tomcat versions. You see, just different code in the end.

Comment: @GhostCat  I ran same code by compiling with Java 1.6 in Tomcat 7 it didn't work.

Comment: What a version of Struts?

Comment: @RomanC We are using Struts 2.0

Comment: It's not possible, what is the question?